# How to add transition between videos when using AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avqueueplayer, avplayerlayer

I am working on a video application that plays a number of videos one after another. The videos are stored in an array of `AVPlayerItem`s. `AVQueuePlayer` is initialized with those `AVPlayerItems` and it automatically plays the videos from that array.

The issue is when it changes to play the next video it gets stuck for a fraction of a second or it creates a jerk at the time it transitions from one to another. I want to improve this transition with some kind of animation such as Fade In and Fade Out while the video is changed.

My code for `AVQueuePlayer`:

```
AVQueuePlayer *mediaPlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:arrPlayerItems];
playerLayer=[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:mediaPlayer];
playerLayer.frame=self.bounds;
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
playerLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = NO;
[self.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
self.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(itemPlayEnded:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[mediaPlayer currentItem]];
```

I tried to create a new layer at the time of the transition and animate the old layer by decreasing its opacity and increasing the opacity of the new layer (to create the desired fade in fade out effect), but it is not working as desired.

The code for the custom transition:

```
-(void)TransitionInVideos {
    if (roundf(CMTimeGetSeconds(mediaPlayer.currentTime))==roundf(CMTimeGetSeconds(mediaPlayer.currentItem.duration))) {
        [self.layer addSublayer:playerLayerTmp];

        //Animation for the transition between videos
        [self performSelector:@selector(FadeIn) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
        [self performSelector:@selector(FadeOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    }
}

-(void)FadeIn {
    CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeAnim.duration = 2.0;
    [playerLayer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(HideLayer) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)FadeOut {
    CABasicAnimation* fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeAnim.duration = 1.0;
    [playerLayerTmp addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(ShowLayer) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

-(void)HideLayer {
    playerLayer.opacity=0.0;
}

-(void)ShowLayer {
    playerLayerTmp.opacity=1.0;
}
```

How can a transition be applied to videos in the `AVQueuePlayer`?

Comment: I want that same If you found your solution then post here It will help others.

Comment: Apple gives sample code using the queue player w/ seamless transition if it helps: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/avloopplayer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can set the opacity for `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction` that will be add to the video while exporting or `AVPlayer` as VideoComposition property and that will create the fade in and fade out effect.

```
 [layerInstruction setOpacityRampFromStartOpacity:1.0 toEndOpacity:0.0 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract([mutableComposition duration], CMTimeMake(Transition_Time, 1)), [mutableComposition duration])];

 [layerInstruction setOpacityRampFromStartOpacity:0.0 toEndOpacity:1.0 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMake(1, 1))];
```

this are the code for giving the effect.

---

More complete examples:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/avloopplayer/Introduction/Intro.html
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: Do you have a more complete example? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Can you provide more details to show how you accomplished the desired effect? A complete code sample would be appreciated.

Comment: Examples: https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Answer (score 2):

we had exactly the same problem in one of our app - and unfortunately, we had to drop the standard player and use logic from this example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Listings/Classes_MyStreamingMovieViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092-Classes_MyStreamingMovieViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8

hope that helps.

Comment: I gone through this sample code earlier.It just changes the video and in that also the black part gets appears for fraction of seconds.What I want is some kind of effects at the time of transition from one video to another video. Well thanks for showing interest and helping !!!

Comment: i know for sure that we had the same issue as you do - we had to play 2 videos - one after another. Using standard AvPlayer control - we got pause for a fraction of second, and/or black flickering. Using the technique from the article above helped us to solve this - now 2 videos are played like it's a single one. I will try to get more insight from our team on what exactly was done.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the desired effect by using two separate AVPlayer objects playing back to back. The players are using different views to play on.

The idea is to fade in the second video player's view before the first video is going to finish.

The demo project can be found here: [IHLoopingVideoPlayerView](https://github.com/ishanhanda/IHLoopingVideoPlayerView)

It loops the same video over and over but the same idea can be applied to any number of videos.

Comment: @iwasrobbed FYI that link requires a login.  Those of us who aren't in that slack channel can't access it.

Comment: @RonLugge Apologies for that, here's sample code from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/avloopplayer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: this was a good solution!  I had to refactor it a bit for my purposes, but all in all you saved me a lot of time.  Thank you!